# Genuine Random Numbers with Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, random

A programm can only produce pseudo random numbers, because it is always deterministic. But with Multithreading you get non-determinism, because of all the effects of scheduling/cache/swaps etc.
Could you use this effect to produce real random numbers, because this depends not only on deterministic code, but also on physical phenomina as latency etc.

Comment: This question is a homework question and has no place in Stack. Furthermore, there has been no effort from the OP.

Comment: You might want to review this article: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: maybe it is not an actual question, maybe the Author just realized this is the case and needed to share their epiphany  with the community?

Comment: maybe the author was serious with his question ... and there might be people who enjoy answering questions more than to question the intention of the op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is used all the time. If you're reading from `/dev/random` on many Unix-like systems, you're probably getting "environmental" effects mixed into the entropy. But don't over-read this as "real random numbers." The effects you're describing still only vary over a limited range, and in some cases may vary over a *very* limited range such that they are very close to deterministic (and "close" is often enough if you build your security around your RNG).

The classic version of this problem is a router booting up and seeding its RNG with latency information from the network. In a very noisy network, this may be pretty random. In a fairly quiet network, this may be very predictable. This is a very real-world problem and difficult to solve in embedded systems.

A lesson from this is to avoid inventing your own RNGs, particularly if you are building security systems on top of them. Research the RNGs your system provides, and use them (or research cryptographic random number generation before embarking on a new solution).

If this subject interests you, [random.org](http://random.org) has some good introductory materials, along with an implementation based on atmospheric data. (Whether even this is "true random" or just "deterministic based on a state we don't know" is an argument for physicists, but it's about as close as we've got.)